# *ngFor shows from the second object

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I can't find the reason to a specific behavior I have in a test angular 2 application

1. I have declared a list of `Customers` in my App Component
2. I have built a child component called `Customer` with in `@Input` parameter of `Customer`
3. In the App html I am passing the customer object via *ngFor to the child component but in the browser I can see only from the second object

Here is my App Component

```
const CUSTOMERS: Customer[] = [
{Id: 1, name: "Adi"},
{Id : 2, name: "Dan"},
{Id : 3, name: "Yossi"},
{Id : 4, name: "DavId"},
{Id : 5, name: "Hadar"},
{Id : 6, name: "Gil"},
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'This is my new app';
  Adi = "This is my name";

  customers = CUSTOMERS;

  ngOnInit (){
    console.log(this.customers);
  }
}

export class Customer {
  Id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Here is the html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let c of customers">
    <my-customer [customer]="c" ></my-customer>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the child component

```
import {Customer} from '../app.component';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-customer',
    templateUrl: './Customer.Component.html',
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() customer: Customer;
    constructor() {

     }

    ngOnInit() { 

    }
}
```

Any reason why I can see only from the second object? 
Meaning I don't see 'Adi' Object

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: It's wired. Try go to Chrome Developer Tools "Element" and check if this <ul> really starts from the second object.

Comment: @CharlesZha it doesn't starts from the second object, the first li is created but the data is presented from the second one on

Answer (score 0):

Its weird. You can check your console and check all the elements are rendered or not.

I Checked your code and created my sample, everything works for me I mean I am able to see all data from customer object.

Check this plunker demo created as per your requirement.

https://plnkr.co/edit/sFR5Uv?p=preview

```
**app.ts**

//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {CustomerComponent} from './child.component'
const CUSTOMERS: Customer[] = [
{Id: 1, name: "Adi"},
{Id : 2, name: "Dan"},
{Id : 3, name: "Yossi"},
{Id : 4, name: "DavId"},
{Id : 5, name: "Hadar"},
{Id : 6, name: "Gil"},
];
export class Customer {
  Id: number;
  name: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let c of customers">
    <my-customer [customer]="c" ></my-customer>
  </li>
</ul>
  `,
})
export class App {

   title = 'This is my new app';
  Adi = "This is my name";

  customers = CUSTOMERS;



  constructor() {

  }

}
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, CustomerComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}



**child.component**


import {Customer} from './app';
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-customer',
    template: '<div>{{customer.name}}</div>',
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() customer: Customer;
    constructor() {

     }

    ngOnInit() { 

    }
}
```